# If $\sin\theta = -\dfrac{1}{2}$ , then what will be the possible values of $\theta$ between $0$ and $2π$?

Tags: trigonometry

I even dont understood the question:
If $\sin\theta = \frac{-1}{2}$ , then what will be the possible values of $\theta$ between $0$ and $ 2π $

Comment: That was a mistake, question edited!

Comment: Have you ever seen $\sin$ function ploted? Here it is: http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-sin-cos-tan-graphs.html Can you spot where the value is $-\frac12$?

Comment: Well, I'm weak at trigonometry, and I don't know much about these things...still I can see a $-0.5$ in the begining of the forth row :p Don't laugh if it sounds silly!

Comment: And where does it cross with the sine curve? (I mean $x$ value) That is your answer - there are two such values from $[0,2\pi]$ Here is a graph to help you: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29+%3D+-1%2F2+where+x+in+[0%2C2pi]

Comment: Is it 90 and 270?

Comment: @Vivek: No, I'm afraid not. $\sin -90^{\circ}=-\sin 90^{\circ}=-1\neq -\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: No. It is $\pi + \frac{\pi}{6}$ and $2\pi - \frac{\pi}{6}$ (or in degrees: $180+30$ and $360-30$). Look at the graph I linked to.

Comment: Thanks!, but please also explain what is $\dfrac{π}{6}$

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{6}$ radians is equal to $30^{\circ}$.

Comment: I mean, why we added/substracted this only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way of observing how many expected solutions we should get is by sketching our function $\sin(x)$ for $0\leq x \leq 2\pi$ along with $x=-\frac{1}{2}$, as follows:

[image: sin graph with x=-(1/2) line]

We see that there are two points at which the two functions intersect, so we should expect two solutions in the interval.

We can find the first solution by using the inverse function of $\sin(x)$:

$$\sin(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\implies x=\arcsin\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

This gives us $x=-\frac{\pi}{6}$ as our principle value. We note that $\sin(x)$ is period every $2\pi$ and therefore we get: $x=\frac{11\pi}{6}$, we note that there must also be a solution at $x=\pi+(2\pi-\frac{11\pi}{6})=\frac{7\pi}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First find the principle angle (i.e. what is $\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2}$, in quadrant $1$) and recall that sine is negative in quadrants $3$ and $4$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin\theta=-\frac12=-\sin\frac\pi6=\sin\left(-\frac\pi6\right)$$

$$\implies\theta=m\pi+(-1)^m\left(-\frac\pi6\right)$$ where $m$ is any integer

When $\displaystyle m$ is even, $=2r$(say)  $\displaystyle\theta=2r\pi-\frac\pi6$

We need $\displaystyle 0\le2r\pi-\frac\pi6\le2\pi\implies 0<r\le1\implies r=1$

Similarly, for odd $m$

Comment: @Vivek, How about this?

Comment: Errr....too complex for me, afterall its trigonometery, thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

sinΘ = -(1/2) at 210 and 330 radians

Comment: Surely you mean degrees?